# Increasing the Memory of a Lambda Function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, latency

We have a Lambda Function whose Memory is 128 MB,

We have it in Production, We are getting thousands(3-4K) of requests per day.

The Lambda  is  exposed externally via an API Gateway which is Regional and  type is REST.

I can clearly Capture the Metrics of API Gateway and Lambda Function.

API Gateway Metrics:

```
 Latency 2000 ms on an  Average,
 Integration Latency 2300ms on an Average.
```

Lambda average Duration is 3 seconds.

Sometimes we even encountering 504 Gateway Timeout Exceptions, Once or twice in a Day.

I am expecting the Latency to decrease If we Increase  the Memory Size,
According to [AWS Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-functions-with-up-to-10-gb-of-memory-and-6-vcpus/)

So,
Will the 504 Gateway Timeout Exceptions disappear If we Increase  the Lambda  Memory Size to around 1 GB(1024 MB)?

Or
What will  be  the ideal  memory size for 10 K requests per each day.?

Answer (score 1):

It's worth knowing that increasing the RAM of a lambda also increases the available CPU. Thus, it is sound to expect better performances in a lot of cases. As a matter of fact, doubling the CPU will often double the price per millisecond, while also dividing the invocation time per 2. Same price, half the latency, a good deal !

### However

These rules of thumb sometimes don't apply at all. What is your lambda actually doing ?

- a lot of computations ? Then increasing CPU (*i.e.* RAM since they grow together) will definitely help
- sending a ton of sequential http requests and wait for remote services to answer ? Then you don't improve anything with more RAM

It's probably worth benchmarking, but as other said you should perhaps find your bottleneck first before spending more money on CPU.

As to finding the best RAM value for you, simply increase it slowly, and watch for changes until you find something satisfactory. The number of request per day isn't really relevant, it's more about fine-tuning your average invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Is it only hitting 3000ms due to an additional cold start latency that's added or is does this also occur when there's an available instance?

With 3000ms, you can jump through all kinds of hoops and loops in order to solve it with memory size, provisioned concurrency and such. But I recommend to try and improve the code/process making this run for such a long time. I would assume that your clients are also not keen on calling an API that responds after 3000ms?

If you can get rid of it being an API, try swapping the API Gateway with SQS and make it more of a 'worker'.

Comment: After Cold Start also,
It  is  3 sec on  an   Average.  Will do the code  optimizations

Comment: Hmm then indeed your best bet will be trying to optimize the code. 3000ms is quite a lot, I'm sure you got this! If we can help out let us know :)